# Perl module for 'file' command?

Tags: perl, file, file-type

On a Linux system I can use the `file` command to detect the type of a file.

Is there a `perl` module that encapsulates this command?

Answer (score 5):

If you know you'll be on a sane Unix, you can just make a system call to `file`.

If you need an independent implementation, [there are several available on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?size=20&q=file+magic). Probably the closest to `file` is [File::MMagic](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::MMagic). This is its own implementation, so it will work on any system, but might not act exactly like `file`.

```
$ head test.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$ file test.pl
test.pl: a /usr/bin/env perl script text executable, ASCII text

$ perl -wlE 'use File::MMagic; $mm = File::MMagic->new; say $mm->checktype_filename(shift)' test.pl
x-system/x-unix;  executable /usr/bin/env script text
```

Comment: @CJ7 I wouldn't be surprised if docx is compressed with zlib. You might have to combine this with a database of file extensions.

Comment: I'm only using this for files that for some reason don't have extensions.

Answer (score 2):

File::MMagic's [built-in magic](https://metacpan.org/source/KNOK/File-MMagic-1.30/MMagic.pm#L1415) is so short, it's useless. Avoid.

Instead use [File::LibMagic](http://p3rl.org/File::LibMagic#RELATED-MODULES), it's the best.

```
$ perl -mFile::LibMagic -MDDS -E \
    'say Dump(File::LibMagic->new
        ->info_from_filename("Startopia EULA English.docx"))'
$HASH1 = {
    description  => 'Microsoft Word 2007+',
    encoding     => 'binary',
    mime_type    => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
    mime_with_encoding => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=binary'
};
```